# Pointer to first byte of a vector<float>

Tags: c++, xaudio2

The pointer to the audio buffer of the `XAUDIO_BUFFER` structure in XAudio2 is defined as `BYTE *pAudioData`. When I was using 16-bit Integer PCM, this is what my program looked like:

```
void buildWaveBuffer(std::vector<unsigned char> &vec)
{
    std::string lineString;
    int lineInt;
    unsigned char lowByte, highByte;
    std::ifstream myfile("sineInt16");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(myfile.good())
        {
            std::getline(myfile,lineString,',');
            lineInt = atoi(lineString.c_str());
            highByte = (lineInt >> 8) & 0x00FF;
            lowByte = lineInt & 0x00FF;
            vec.push_back(lowByte);
            vec.push_back(highByte);
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

`"sineInt16"` being a .csv file. Since the vector is organized sequentially in the memory, I would simply do `pAudioData = &vec[0]` and it would work. What if I want to change the format of my .csv to `float`? How do I give a pointer to the first byte in the vector? Should I use another container like a simple array of chars?

Comment: What does the address of the first byte avail you? The byte-wise interpretation of a float is completely unrelated to its actual value. Can XAudio2 cope with that?

Comment: Your loop is wrong. It will read the file incorrectly.

Comment: @Konrad Honestly I'm not sure, I'm guessing that since I'm specifying in the options that the samples are in a Float32 format and that each samples have 32 bits, XAudio2 will read the first 4 bytes before interpreting the value?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't know why you say that, I get no errors and I have a very nice sine wave coming out of my speakers.

Comment: @Deli Nawaz is correct since your loop doesn’t handle failure to read properly: what happens when `getline` fails? Your code won’t cope with that, and `getline` probably isn’t the most appropriate here anyway. Use the streaming operator for `float` and `char` instead.

Comment: @Konrad I changed my code to use the streaming operator instead. Works much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I give a pointer to the first byte in the vector?

The exact same way, but I'm not sure it will do what you expect. Read the comments to your question.